# Updating Stripe Payment Intent throws Authentication error (401 error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks, stripe-payment-intent

I have the following code which uses a stripe webhook to update the customer database based on the payment intent event from stripe. The signature is verified and it works fine. But when the update payment intent API is called , it throws a 401 error like the following

*

> You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in
> the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization:
> Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See
> https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help
> at https://support.stripe.com/

- 

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);

const handleStripeWebhook = async (req, res) => {
  const payload = req.rawBody || req.body;
  const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      payload,
      sig,
      process.env.STRIPE_SIGN_KEY
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case "payment_intent.succeeded":
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
     

      // Do something with the paymentIntent
      console.log("Payment succeeded:");
         let info = "something"
      
        // update the payment intent with someInfo
        const modifiedPaymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.update(
          `${paymentIntent.id}`,
          {
            metadata: {
              someInfo: info,
            },
          }
        );
      
      try {
        // ...some code
      } catch (error) {
        // ...some code
      }
      break;
    case "payment_intent.payment_failed":
      const failedPaymentIntent = event.data.object;
      // Do something with the failedPaymentIntent
      console.log("Payment failed");
      break;
    default:
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  }
  res.status(200).json({ received: true });
};
```

Any idea as to what could be wrong here?

Comment: which Stripe API Key are you using? the secret or the publishable key?

Comment: Secret key. The same works for the signature verification. Should I be using a different key?  I was trying to do it as explained here. https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update

Comment: Secret key is the way to go, I was just checking whether it was a misusage of keys. the other thing I can think of is the fact that `process.env.STRIPE_KEY` might be empty for some reason. could you double check that?

Comment: Yes,  I checked it using the debugger by adding a breakpoint on that line. I verified that the key is there. Moreover, the signature verification also works based on the same key. I verified the paymentIntent.id as well.

Comment: Since I am using test mode, could that be a reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, I resolved it by reinitiating the stripe object. it looks like stripe object loses the secret key after the signature verification. Now, this is my workaround. But if anyone knows a better approach, please share.

```
const stripeNew = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);
```

Inserting this line and modifying the update payment api with *stripeNew* worked for me. Here is the revised code.

```
const modifiedPaymentIntent = await stripeNew.paymentIntents.update(
      `${paymentIntent.id}`,
      {
        metadata: {
          someInfo: info,
        },
      }
    );
```

Comment: which version of the stripe-node SDK are you using?

Comment: Latest one. 11.11.0